# New record on both HABTM models

Tags: php, cakephp, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to add new records for two HABTM associated models in the same form submission.

I have two models: Booking & PaymentItem. These two have an HABTM relationship. I've joined them with a BookingPaymentItem model (I needed to access this model at a later stage to track payments made).

It's not important to know all the fields in the bookings table but here are the concerning ones in the payment items model:

```
**payment_items - table**
id
name
description
price

**booking_payment_items**
id
booking_id
payment_item_id
quantity
```

So, in the Bookings add view, I have all the booking fields I want to add. Now, on form submission, I need to have two new payment items created - accommodation and deposit. So, my idea is to add some hidden fields and only display fields: accommodation cost and deposit amount to the user. These two new payment items need to be associated to the also newly created booking (and by extension, BookingPaymentItem entry).

Here's the form setup in my add view:

```
<? echo $this->Form->hidden('PaymentItem.1.id', array('value'=>$this->Text->uuid(), 'div' => false)); ?>
<? echo $this->Form->input('PaymentItem.1.price', array('label' => 'Total Tariff','div' => false)) ?>
<? echo $this->Form->hidden('PaymentItem.1.name', array('value'=>'Accommodation', 'div' => false)); ?>
<? echo $this->Form->hidden('PaymentItem.1.description', array('value'=>'Accommodation', 'div' => false)); ?>
<? echo $this->Form->hidden('PaymentItem.2.id', array('value'=>$this->Text->uuid(), 'div' => false)); ?>
<? echo $this->Form->input('PaymentItem.2.price', array('label' => false,'div' => false)); ?>
<? echo $this->Form->hidden('PaymentItem.2.name', array('value'=>'Deposit', 'div' => false)); ?>
<? echo $this->Form->hidden('PaymentItem.2.description', array('value'=>'Deposit', 'div' => false)); ?>
```

Here's the request->data variable dump:

```
array(
'Booking' => array(
    'property_id' => 'COC1127',
    'checkin' => '2013-01-23',
    'checkout' => '2013-01-30',
    'guest_id' => '02',
    'ownervisible' => '1',
    'adults' => '1',
    'children' => '0',
    'infants' => '0',
    'deposit_due_date' => '2013-01-16'
),
'PaymentItem' => array(
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '50f4612d-3858-4d68-9dee-0b70c2e1e283',
        'price' => '1200',
        'name' => 'Accommodation',
        'description' => 'Accommodation'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '50f4612d-a334-4615-ba8d-0b70c2e1e283',
        'price' => '400',
        'name' => 'Deposit',
        'description' => 'Deposit'
    )
)
)
```

Results:

1. Booking model saves perfectly as expected
2. No payment item entry recorded
3. No booking payment item entry recorded

I played around with this a bit and got more saved but nothing that matched what I needed to do.

I need the booking added, the two payment items added and the associating booking_payment_item entry added with the ids.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using HABTM instead of Booking hasMany PaymentItem? The reason I ask is because it looks like you're wanting to create new PaymentItems on each submission, which defeats the purpose of reusing them with HABTM. Secondly, you're adding the id manually which causes Cake to try and `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`. I don't know if it falls back to insert if the record is missing (which it would be in this case), but either way it's a bit odd.

Comment: Well, diving a bit more into the specifics of the app - there's also an option to associate addons to the booking. The app needs to track payments of Accommodation, Deposits and Addons at a later stage. This became tricky if I was tracking payments from two different models. With the current setup, I can track all payments items (accommodation, deposits and all other adhoc addons) and simply categorize them using a payment_items_category table. That means that my PaymentItem model has a hasMany relationship with Payments. This works out better for reporting on payments for a specific booking.

Comment: Also, for redundancy avoidance purposes, the idea is to add a set number of addons and simply choose from a drop down when the user wants to add the extra item to the booking. The laternative, should this prove fruitless, is to use the hasMany relationship and just enter in duplicates of the data - not the best solution but I'd sacrifice for functionality at this point

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand, but it seems to me that PaymentItem is the join table with the extra field "price" dictated by the user, pointing to both a booking and a payment type (like accommodation, deposit). Also still don't know why you added your own random ID instead of letting cake forge the relationship. Can you jump on IRC or SO chat? I think just talking it through would help.

Comment: @KyleO'Brien : can u please post on how are to trying to save these data in the controller function.I believe that if you have setup the model associations correctly then yould could perform a Model::saveAssociated call to get the data saved to multiple models...please check this link and see if its useful....http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array